# ImageMagick for PHP on Windows 7 Professional 64bit?

Tags: php, windows, windows-7, 64-bit, iis-7.5

Morning all,

Day 2 - I knew this was going to get sticky...

Windows 7 Professional 64bit
IIS 7.5
PHP 5.3.19 (as suggested/installed by Web Platform Installer)

All working fine.

ImageMagick 6.8.2.2 2013-01-28 Q16 - 32bit version. (64bit version tried yesterday but couldn't get php_imagick.dll working)

Working

php_imagick.dll:

`PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\ext\php_imagick.dll' - The specified module could not be found. in Unknown on line 0`

- Does anyone have any experience of this?
- Do I need a 64bit version of PHP?
- Should I be aiming at a newer or older PHP version?
- How do I find out if my the version of PHP (installed by WPI) is 32 or 64bit?
- Is it best to stick to 32bit when using Win7 64 or throw caution to the wind and use all 64bit versions?

I was assured that the days of incompatibility were over when I opted to upgrade to 64bit windows. I'm not young, but I'm still foolish, obviously...

My plan today is to run through every possible combination, including dropping IIS and using Apache. This will be a mammoth task, but I've got no other real options. Anything I find I will post here for future generations.

Thanks for any comments/help/observations.

Steve

Comment: Works fine for me with a basic version of xampp. But I remember i had troubles finding a working version of imagemagick.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I was hoping to have something more comprehensive than this, but my fairly exhaustive investigations points to the following:

ImageMagick-x.x.x-x-Qx-x64-dll **isn't** compatible with x64 PHP Dlls.

There are sketching reports of x64 builds working, but for every report of a working installation, there are 10 that don't work. There are some admirable efforts to document this, but the chances are, it isn't going to work.

I've tried Nginx(x64), Apache(x64) and IIS servers, using PHP 5.3(x64) and 5.4(x64) TS and NTS.

I always get the "%1" or the "module not found" issue.

The answer is to steer clear of x64 binaries. Windows 7 x64 is fine, but don't use any other x64 components.

I'm interested in any other anecdotes, but I seriously doubt I would spend any more time on this. Given the relative hostility to Windows from the PHP, Apache and ImageMagick camps, a fix is likely to come from elsewhere.